# Circuit design when using batteries

Tags: power, circuit-design, electrical, volts

I'm new to making any electrical desings that don't have a manual.

I have six 12 V 20 Ah Lead-Acid batteries connected in series.

Can a 12 V 14 Ah or/and a 12 V 6.5 Ah battery(ies) be connected in any manner in which it won't harm the life span of the "original" six batteries?

Comment: Depends, how are these batteries charged? Are the additional batteries also lead-acid?

Comment: Please fix your title to describe your problem, not your negative expectation. Omit the prologue – you can't make anything shorter and simpler by starting it with "short and simple. Anything else..." ;) .

Comment: Sorry was not trying to be a jerk or sound un-Greatful. And yes all batteries describer are valve regulated lead-acid

Comment: Hey Graham, don't worry. This is better, I'm going to go ahead and shorten down your title a little and completely remove the prologue :)

Comment: @GrahamMcGoldrick Assuming you don't have a 6V-12V battery, I made some changes in your text. Please check, hit the edit link to undo / improve my edits. The clearer the question, the more viewers it attracts, the higher the chance of an answer being useful to you.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank You appreciate taking your time in helping with proper terminology and best practices in finding answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

This article from all about curcuits might be nifty in what you are looking for it better. Pay close attention to the review section

And the paragraph above it

https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-11/practical-considerations-batteries/

I